# Upgrade NuGet Powershell Cmdlets

Tags: powershell, packages

I'm attempting to use NuGet powershell cmdlets mentioned [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/powershell-reference).

I'm having a problem with the fact that I use VS2015 and my machines NuGet package source is pointing to "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json", but the powershell cmdlets only work when I specify a source of "http://www.nuget.org/api/v2/".

I also am missing the cmdlets that only exist in v3.

How do I upgrade my powershell nuget version?